# Use windows explorer to connect to a server with username and password

Tags: networking, windows-explorer, connection

I am using this format to connect to a server i have (from the windows explorer itslelf) :

```
\\serveraddress\D$\test
```

and that i get prompt for username and password,

i need to know is there a way that i could write the username and password in that line
something like when connecting to ftp ;

```
ftp://user:passowrd@url
```

Thnaks

Comment: I cant test this right now , but doesn't the password dialog give you an option to save the password?

Comment: it does but i need another process to have access this way ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by first authenticating to the server with

> net use \\serveraddress\D$\test /user:someone@mydomain.com [password]

Then you will be able to type the following without a prompt for the length of your user session

> \\serveraddress\D$\test

You can add the `/persistent:yes` to the first command to make it permanent

See the help for the `Net Use` command from the command prompt for more into

> Net Use /?

Comment: I keep getting the following error : Mupltiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all prevous connections to the server or shared resource and try again. and i ensured that i disconnected any connection to that server and still getting it. maybe i am writing the username and password format wrong ? if it is admin password , it should be : /user:admin [password] ?

Comment: you probably already authenticated from a previous test.  logoff and try again.